# React error: "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am getting an error that says "each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. When I check the Components using React Developer Tools I don't see any duplicates - what am I doing wrong?

```
  return (
    <>
    <Modal
        isOpen={modalIsOpen}
        onRequestClose={closeModal}
    >
      { modalIsOpen ? (
        <Note
        key={'ModalNote' + modalNote.id}
        id={modalNote.id}
        title={modalNote.title}
        text={modalNote.text}
        date={modalNote.date}
        deleteNote={deleteNote}
        closeNote={closeModal}
        />
      ) : ('')
      }
      
    </Modal>
    <div className="notesForm">
      <AddNote addNoteHandler={addNoteHandler}/>
    </div>
    <div className="notes">
      {notes.map((note) => (
        <>
        <Note
          key={note.id}
          id={note.id}
          title={note.title}
          text={note.text}
          date={note.date}
          deleteNote={deleteNote}
          closeNote={closeModal}
          openModal={openModal}
          modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
        />
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
    </>
  );
```

Comment: Are you getting error or warning?

Comment: I think you should also add the key on the top element

Comment: Here the top level element is fragment, to add key to the fragment it should be as `<React.Fragment key={...}>` not just `<>`

Comment: In addition to the already valid answers, a sidenote: If you only have a single child in a fragment, the fragment may be removed, so you could also just remove the `<>`/`</>` around your Note component.

Comment: Thank you all! I didn't realize I had the fragment in there, and as @geisterfurz007 noted it wasn't necessary. KcH's suggestion also worked (<React.Fragment key={...}>) and it's good to know we can add keys to fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys are to be added to the outermost element returned from the `map`

Here in your e.g its the fragment `<>`, to add the key to the fragment you should be using `<React.Fragment>` for shorthand as [shorter syntax doesn't support keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax)

```
{notes.map((note) => (
        <React.Fragment key={note.id}>
        <Note
          key={note.id}
          id={note.id}
          title={note.title}
          text={note.text}
          date={note.date}
          deleteNote={deleteNote}
          closeNote={closeModal}
          openModal={openModal}
          modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
        />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Instead of Fragment add div, It might works.
-> And if You want Fragment then:

**<React.Fragment key={note.id}>**

```
  <div key={note.id}>
    <Note
      key={note.id}
      id={note.id}
      title={note.title}
      text={note.text}
      date={note.date}
      deleteNote={deleteNote}
      closeNote={closeModal}
      openModal={openModal}
      modalIsOpen={modalIsOpen}
    />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These other answers are fine, but to ensure every key is unique **do not** use a numerical key. It's better to use a combination of text and numbers for your keys or, even better, a short id - https://www.npmjs.com/package/shortid

```
<Note
  key={`note-${note.id}`}
  id={note.id}
  title={note.title}
/>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I am not sure this is true; the result (in terms of uniqueness) is identical whether you prefix it or not. keys don't have to be unique across the entire application; just inside a single block.

Comment: generally speaking, non-sequential keys are better for performance - https://robinpokorny.com/blog/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern/

This is an article reference by the React docs

Comment: That article refers to using the iteration index as key prop which is indeed frowned upon because it might cause wrong renders (the key stays the same but the data shifts when adding a new item at the start). As long as the key is supplied by the mapped value, sequential values are "fine" since they stay consistent even throughout moves / swaps of items because they move / swap with their data.

Comment: fair enough. I would still recommend OP uses a text + number value for this key rather than simply an id just in case